# Enabling wifi or bluetooth before user login in Linux

Tags: wifi, wireless, bluetooth

What would the security implications be of enabling and using wifi and / or bluetooth before a user logs into the system in a Linux box?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you planning to use a type of script to enable the Wifi or Bluetooth?

Comment: That is the part I am not sure. Would you happen to know at what stage networkmanager (or any other network tools - wicd...) is enabled in the boot process?

Answer (score 1):

At a bare minimum, you expose the account the service runs as. If the service is subject to attack, then that becomes a vulnerability.

This is no different from exposing any other service, except that it is exposing a communications channel. The important question is, "what else on the box is using that communication channel?" You need to chase down the cascading services.

Comment: Hi Schroeder and sorry for the late reply.  Thank you for your insight on the security of this.  Yes, the account will be exposed, but hopefully it will be the only thing.  Would it be possible to isolate this particular channel to be used just for this purpose?